# Creating a class that extends keyListener

Tags: java, swing, overriding, listener, extends

In my java project, I want to check the input in each JTextField in a few different classes (with the exact same code)..

Right now I have the same code copied over and over and I was suggested with 2 options:

1. Create a method and call the method instead.
2. Create a new class that extends from another class (I don't know which yet) that has the method needed.

The code I'm using now is:

```
totalAmount.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
@Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    //do something
    }
});
```

And the new class is:

```
public class Listener extends KeyAdapter {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0){
    //do something
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know if I'm extending the right class, and how to use the new class I've written...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) In your case `totalAmount.addKeyListener(instanceOfYourListener);` 2) But you should use a [`DocumentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for checking for changes in a `JTextField`, not a `KeyListener`.

Comment: 1) totalAmount.addKeyListener(new Listener() { keyTyped(arg0);} ? It doesn't work... 2) I'm trying to check each key typed by the user, and this is what eclipse gave me... Right now the code I have is working, I just need to copy it everytime...

Comment: One way would be to do `totalAmount.addKeyListener(new Listener());`. However, you can also only use one instance of the listener for all of your textfields.

Comment: @orohev I added an answer. I hope it helps. If you feel it is sufficiently correct could you accept it using the tick next to the answer and upvote. But if it is wrong let me know :)

Comment: It seems the solution I was looking for, thanks! To be honest I didn't get the last sentence. However, if you mean I won't be able to use another listener type in my textfields, for now I don't see a reason I'd need it. Though it will be nice if there is another option rather than creating another class for each listener...

Comment: @orohev If I implied that I didn't mean to. The second way of doing it (the [`document listener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html)) is just another way people do it. You can use as many listeners with the `JTextField` as you would like.

Comment: @orohev Also it is good to click the tick next to the answer to show that the question has been answered and it also lets the author of the answer know that their answer is sufficiently correct enough to be the accepted answer

Comment: I did tick next to your answer :) I'll look into the document listener again...

Comment: DON'T use `KeyListener` (generally, but especially) with text components, use either a `DocumentListener` or a ` DocumentFilter` or the key bindings API, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), 
[Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners), 
[Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you are wanting with your key adapter you would use

```
totalAmount.addKeyListener(new Listener());
```

and your code of your key adapter is correct.

```
public class Listener extends KeyAdapter {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0){
        //do something
    }
}
```

To get the text from a `JTextField` you could either use this code inside your `keyAdapter`

```
System.out.println(totalAmount);
```

or, preferably you could use a document listener. This would be done by

```
public class documentListener implements DocumentListener //This is a listener
{
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){

    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
        int lengthMe = e.getDocument().getLength();
        System.out.println(e.getDocument().getText(0,lengthMe));
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
        int lengthMe = e.getDocument().getLength();
        System.out.println(e.getDocument().getText(0,lengthMe));
    }
}
```

and it would be added to the `JTextField` with

```
totalAmount.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new documentListener());
```

Comment: A 1+ up-vote for the "preferably you could use a DocumentListener". The OP should in fact **not** be adding a KeyListener to a JTextField, since this can alter the native behavior of the text field in bad and unexpected ways. I'm not sure which key he's listening for, but if its the enter key, then the best solution would be to add an ActionListener to the JTextField.